# converting video with php and ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

i am trying a simple test to learn how to convert videos with ffmpeg via PHP as they are uploaded to my site (to .mp4).
however am i missing something, as my simple test is doing nothing....

code (simplified)

```
$videoFile = '/home/xxx/public_html/dev/videos/1746/sample.avi';
exec("ffmpeg -i $videoFile -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 /home/xxx/public_html/dev/videos/1746/test.mp4");
```

i have also trired

```
system("ffmpeg -i $videoFile -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 /home/xxx/public_html/dev/videos/1746/test.mp4");
```

and

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $videoFile -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 /home/xxx/public_html/dev/videos/1746/test.mp4");
```

Also if i try

```
echo exec('ffmpeg -formats');
```

i get no output

none of the above convertion tests work and no test.mp4 file is created.
i have error reporting turned on yet get no errors.

any advice would be welcomed please

Comment: Well, is ffmpeg installed at all? Does it work from a shell session?

Comment: i dont have shell access, but it is installed (ok i think) if i try echo ('ffmpeg -version'); i get lots of libary and version numbers

Comment: echo exec('ffmpeg -version'); gives me this "libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change output like this 
    exec('ffmpeg -formats >> out.log')
and look in it.

Comment: Redirecting stderr would make sense.

Comment: just tried this, i get no log file (i assume it will put the out.log in the same location as the php page, but i have also checked the root)

Comment: @mario what does "Redirecting stderr" mean? (sorry)

Comment: It means redirect output into "standard error output". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Answer (score 0):

Specify the complete path to ffmpeg executable and that will solve the issue.

Eg : **/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg**